# Can I filter a post type based on comment moderation settings?

Tags: custom-post-types

I want to block front end submitted posts if they contain certain words or website addresses and such. I can set the post type all to draft when submitted but want to keep set up to publish but be able to moderate them somewhat.

I am currently submitting the post with a gravity form. I want my cpt to be like a comment really and hoped I could hook into the comments system to moderate posts based on settings in the discussion settings.

I am looking for direction or suggestions on how to best do this. A pro coder I am not but I can figure things out with a start or good tutorial.

Everything on moderation I find is for comments.

Comment: Could you please add more details to your question? The code you are using to save the post would be a good start.

Comment: The post is submitted with a gravity form. I have no code but will set something up based on livearoha suggestion below.

Answer (score 0):

Within the loop you can output the post only if it does not match your banned words

```
<?php
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    $banned = array('badword', 'http://');
    $ok = true;
    foreach ( $banned as $value ) {
        if ( stristr( $post->post_content, $value ) ) {
            $ok = false;
        }
    }
    if ( $ok ) : ?>
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php endif;
endwhile;
?>
```